# How to create custom Artisan commands to generate Bitbucket CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket, laravel-artisan, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to create a custom Artisan command to generate the boiler pate for Bitbucket CI/CD Pipeline.

Comment: Those are two tasks that you can solve independently. Also, have you tried anything already?

Comment: I have already created the bitbucket pipeline yml script manualy. But i want an to create it with one single artisan command. Which generate the boiler plate for pipline script.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new command, you may use the make:command Artisan command. This command will create a new command class in the app/Console/Commands directory. Don't worry if this directory does not exist in your application - it will be created the first time you run the make:command Artisan command:

php artisan make:command SendEmails

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands